# Rename filename on windows enviroment github workflow

Tags: python

I was trying to process some data in a GitHub action.

However, due to a Japanese file name, I can not read the file successfully by:

```py
pd.read_csv('C:\\202204_10エリア計.csv')
```

And I was trying to rename it before read it by:

```py
for filename in os.listdir(download_path):
  if filename.startswith('202204'):
    filename = filename.encode('utf-8').decode(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))
    print(filename) # this print '202204_10エリア計.csv' on github action
    os.rename(os.path.join(download_path, filename), os.path.join(download_path, '202204.csv')
```

But it gets error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\202204_10エリア計.csv' -> 'C:\\202204.csv'
```

Comment: The `filename = filename.encode('utf-8').decode(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))` must be changing the filename into something that does not exist. It is unclear why you would expect it to.

Comment: incidentally what happens if you just remove the encode/decode step entirely?  I've never needed to meddle with encoding, and you *shouldn't* ( :D ) if you stay in python-land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to sidestep the encoding/decoding entirely with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib):

```py
from pathlib import Path

fn = next(p for p in Path(download_path).glob("*.csv") if p.name.startswith("202204"))
fn.rename(fn.with_stem("202204"))
```

This is a bit of a workaround to whatever the real issue is, however.

That said I have never needed to meddle with the encoding when using `os.path`, and a quick search of the docs doesn't turn up anything, so you may be fine if you simple remove your encoding/decoding step.  I would expect the `os.path` api to use the same internal representation throughout.

Comment: thank you and sorry for the late reply:)